# Highlight a cell on one worksheet if another cell on a different worksheet doesn't have the exact same text

Tags: google-docs

I am using a spreadsheet for accounting purposes.  I have separate sheets for budget, categories, and report.
I want to know how to use conditional formatting to accomplish the following:
If I change a subcategory in my categories sheet (cell A5), I want the content to match the text in my budget sheet (cell A13).  If it doesn’t match exactly then (cell A5) would be highlighted pink.  And if it doesn’t match exactly the text in my report sheet (cell A23), then (cell A5) would be highlighted brown.
In this forum I was told to use indirect() for cells in multiple sheets, but everything I have tried has not worked.  I must confess that I am a novice to Google docs spreadsheets.  If someone could give me a very, very simple example of matching the text of a cell on one sheet to the text in a cell on a different sheet it would be very useful.  It is used to remind a person who adds or changes a subcategory on one sheet, that it needs to be added or changed on another sheet or two to keep the document uncorrupted.

Comment: What database? MSAccess? I dont think so.. Guessing MSAccess or Excel or Google docs

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting cell A5 and click Format > Conditional formatting > 'Value is not equal to':

`=INDIRECT("Budget!A13")`

`=INDIRECT("Report!A23")`

Note that I've set these up as two separate rules, with the 'Report' rule being evaluated first.  This can be changed by dragging the dropping in the 
rules window though

See this example Sheet and change the value in cell A5 to see it working: https://goo.gl/ZGzLVv